# Como inserir dados em DB com jQuery/Javascript sem usar PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, banco-de-dados

Eu estou aprendendo Javascript e jQuery e estou querendo fazer um pequeno site para testar a inserção de dados em um banco de dados. Não tenho conhecimentos em PHP, gostaria de saber se é possível inserir dados em um banco de dados somente com Javascript ou jQuery. Gostaria também de saber qual a maneira mais eficiente/prática que vocês recomendam para essa tarefa.

Comment: Lembre-se que PHP não é a única maneira de interagir com um banco de dados. O mundo de programação server-side é muito diverso e você pode usar quase qualquer linguagem de programação pra gerar seu HTML e interagir com o banco de dados.

Comment: É possivel manipular bancos através de JavaScript, porém o banco de dados tem que estar na maquina em que a pagina será aberta, ou por unidade de rede mapeada. No caso o único navegador que consegui utilizar foi o internet explorer, os outros bloqueam por segurança. Mas que dá, dá.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você disse em um [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2958/como-inserir-dados-em-mysql-com-jquery-javascript-sem-usar-php#comment3452_2964):

> O que eu pretendo fazer é algo bem simples para treinar algumas coisas como HTML5, CSS3 e javascript, quero fazer um pequeno "banco de dados" com nomes de filmes que já assisti e os que ainda quero ver.

#### Se estiver usando um servidor

**E recomendo que use um, procure um pacote como xampp.**

Você quer mesmo fazer um banco em MySQL? É para aprender a lidar com SQL, ou a fazer um site dinâmico? Para algo assim eu esqueceria o SQL e usaria um arquivo json no servidor. Você puxa o arquivo para o JavaScript com o ajax do jQuery.

Exemplo de arquivo:

```js
[
   { "titulo": "ET", ano: 1982 },
   { "titulo": "Indiana Jones", ano: 1981 }
]
```

#### Se for tudo local

**Você deveria estar usando um servidor.**

Neste caso, crie um arquivo JS com um array literal:

```js
var dados = [
   { titulo: 'ET', ano: 1982 },
   { titulo: 'Indiana Jones', ano: 1981 }
];
```

Answer (score 16):

Esqueça essa ideia. Acessar o banco de dados diretamente via javascript criaria seríssimos problemas de segurança na sua aplicação, afinal com um simples firebug, qualquer um poderia alterar o javascript ou usar o próprio console do javascript para colocar qualquer comando SQL, inclusive um `DROP DATABASE` lá.

E antes disso, você teria que se virar em gerenciar a conexão com o banco de dados diretamente no javascript, e isso não será nada fácil, se é que seria possível.

Além disso, mesmo que você consiga fazer o javascript conectar no banco de dados, uma vez que o javascript roda no browser, você teria que expor o servidor SQL em uma rede pública com o login e senha podendo ser obtidos do javascript. E daí você já deu o seu banco de dados para qualquer hacker na internet fazer o que quiser.

Comment: Obrigado pela informação amigo! Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer essa interação com o banco de dados? O que eu pretendo fazer é algo bem simples para treinar algumas coisas como HTML5, CSS3 e javascript, quero fazer um pequeno "banco de dados" com nomes de filmes que já assisti e os que ainda quero ver. Minha namorada resolveu fazer uma lista dessas so que no word! Ai pensei porque não tentar fazer um site com essa mesma funcionalidade só que de maneira dinâmica? So que meu principal problema é com o banco de dados, eu poderia fazer com o localStorage mas quero aprender a usar uma DB.

Comment: A melhor forma é exatamente colocar um back-end por mais simples que seja, em PHP, Perl, Java, C# ou o que for, que é para onde você vai direcionar as chamadas do front-end. E então o back-end vai até o banco de dados. Pode parecer algo chato e desnecessariamente pesado inicialmente, mas não é.

Comment: Concordo com a resposta, muito pertinente por sinal.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode trabalhar com dados no **MySQL** usando o **node.js** que é um **JavaScript no lado servidor**. Existe uma briga muito grande entre o **PHP** e o node.js em várias questões de performance. Aí vai de você estudar e tentar entrar nesse mundo do node.

Segue um link de exemplo utilizando node.js com MySQL...

[http://blog.josedacruz.com/2013/07/19/learning-node-js-using-mysql/#.UumSzGRdUrg](http://blog.josedacruz.com/2013/07/19/learning-node-js-using-mysql/)

Answer (score 3):

Olá vi está questão e pensei, acho que sei o que ele quer.

Bem você não quer criar uma back-end complexo e trabalhoso para fazer alguns treinamentos como você falou, e pelo que percebi não gostaria de usar outra linguagem outro "Mundo" para o mesmo.

Tenho uma sugestão simples e elegante (rápida) que não fere a segurança da aplicação e funciona perfeitamente, [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/), para você que parece estar melhor familiarizado com javascript, você vai estar em casa, curva de aprendizado simples e é uma grande ferramenta.

O NodeJS trabalha muito bem com MongoBD (um banco orientando a objetos com dados em formato JSON) e MySQL.

Recomento no mínimo dar uma olhada sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível utilizar o MySQL diretamente com javascript/jquery sem um script que rode no lado do servidor como já disseram.

Mas para o uso simples como o seu, você pode baixar um script como esse REST-API e mudar as tabelas e campos que deseja utilizar: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/restful-services-with-jquery-php-and-the-slim-framework/
O formato de entrada e saída é JSON, facilmente utilizado com jquery e todos os outros frameworks de MV (Backbone, Angular, etc)

Ainda por cima aprende a mexer com REST, HTTP Requests e afins.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser aprender como manipular um banco de dados e retornar o resultado em HTML, eu aconselho como os amigos citaram acima que primeiramente, aprenda lógica de programação, posteriormente uma linguagem server-side (PHP,ASP.NET,JAVA,C#,PYTHON...), pois partir para JSON, Node.JS vai exigir boa experiência e conhecimento de causa em termos de programação web!
Também existe no HTML5 o IndexedDB, onde é possível manipular no seu próprio navegador um banco de dados mais simplista, para você aprender pode ser até interessante.
Segue um tutorial a respeito:
http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/

Espero que o conteúdo lhe seja útil!

Abraços

Answer (score 0):

Não, **isso não é possivel**, o JavaScript é uma linguagem de uso *client-side*, sendo assim, é **executada no navegador do usuário**, não tendo **nenhuma relação** com o servidor. Portanto não tem acesso direto ao banco de dados.

O Javascript é usado basicamente para a manipulação dinâmica de conteúdos no site através do browser e para execução de requisições.

Comment: Existem diversas soluções que implementam Javascript do lado do servidor também. Node.js é um bom exemplo e poderia ser utilizado pelo OP.