# Entendendo o arquivo JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tenho um código parecido a este no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pedrogelli/4D9ex/4/). No meu servidor WAMP em casa que fiz pra tentar trabalhar com o JSON (o JSFiddle não contém o arquivo JSON pra testar).

Em uma pergunta que fiz sobre [como inserir dados em um *database* com jQuery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2958/como-inserir-dados-em-db-com-jquery-javascript-sem-usar-php) me responderam que seria uma boa opção armazenar os dados em arquivos JSON. O autor da resposta me mostrou como seria mais ou menos a sintaxe do arquivo JSON. Disse que poderia fazer o seguinte:

```
[
   { titulo: 'ET', ano: 1982 },
   { titulo: 'Indiana Jones', ano: 1981 }
]
```

Em meus testes com esse código do jsfiddle funcionaram bem quando o arquivo JSON estava no formato:

```
{
    "Titulo": "Até que a sorte nos separe",
    "segundo": "segundo valor",
    "terceiro": "terceiro valor, o ultimo valor não precisa de virgula"
}
```

Mas quando eu coloquei no formato que o autor da resposta da minha primeira pergunta mostrou, o click no link "Click me to list" não dispara nada.

Gostaria de saber qual é a diferença entre as duas sintaxes, pois quero fazer um pequeno site com um pequeno banco de dados com informações sobre os filmes que já assisti e os que ainda vou ver. Um link sobre onde conseguir essas informações de como montar um arquivo JSON e como acessar esses valores seria uma boa.

Eu utilizo o método `$.ajax()` para resgatar meu JSON que está dentro de um arquivo ***.json** conforme código:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'js/vendor/testedb.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {


        var item = [];

        $.each(data, function(key,val) {
            item.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
        });

        $('<ul/>',{
            'class': 'myclass',
            html: item.join('')
        }).appendTo('body');


    },
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert("some problem");
        }
    },

});
```

Comment: Esclarecendo sua dúvida sobre postar JSON aqui, coloque seu JSON da pergunta, se precisar ajuda para editar, fazemos para você. Coloque o máximo que puder na pergunta a não ser que seja algo muito grande (o que provavelmente estaria errado para ajudar o problema).

Comment: Editei minha resposta, como você pediu, @Pedro Gelli

Comment: Adicionei uma nova solução adaptada para o seu método @PedroGelli, porém eu aconselho a você adicionar o código do `$.ajax()` aqui na questão pois ele é extremamente importante.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como fui eu que sugeri o JSON e criei a confusão, vou me explicar: o JSON que postei na outra resposta era inválido (já corrigi), pois em JSON as chaves precisam estar entre aspas duplas, assim como valores do tipo *String*.

Portanto, o arquivo JSON poderia conter exatamente [o que o Gabriel Ribeiro sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3260/entendendo-o-arquivo-json/3269#3269):

```
[
    {
        "Titulo": "Até que a sorte nos separe",
        "duracao": "120 min"
    },
    {
        "Titulo": "Matrix",
        "duracao": "140 min"
    }
]
```

<sup>(removi os caracteres acentuados para evitar problemas, embora sejam válidos.)</sup>

Um exemplo em jQuery para obter e usar esses dados via ajax seria:

```
$.getJSON(url_do_json, function(dados) {
    for(var i=0; i<dados.length; i++) {
        $(document.body).append('<div>' + dados[i].titulo + ', ' + dados[i].duracao + '</div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Isso substitui o codigo usado no $.ajax()? Digo devo apagar todo o $.ajax() e usar o $.getJSON()?

Comment: Isso é um atalho para `$.ajax` com determinadas opções já definidas para pegar json. Tanto faz qual você usa.

Comment: Otimo! Obrigado agora consigo listar as propriedades desses objetos. Posso perguntar agora como eu insiro um novo objeto JSON (Filme)? Eu defini variaveis com prompt quando o usuario clicar o link. Mas como vou inserir o valor dessas variaveis em um novo objeto JSON? Eu dei uma olhada no jquery.com mas não consegui achar nada que me ajude. É usando o jQuery.parseJSON? Pode me dar uma mão? To perdido.  http://jsfiddle.net/pedrogelli/LAapR/1/

Comment: @PedroGelli Se você vai querer *salvar* esse json, aí vai precisar mexer com scripting do lado do servidor (seja em php, js com node, c# asp.net, python, o que você quiser). Mas ficando só no js, para inserir mais um filme na tela, dei uma forcinha lá no seu fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LAapR/2/. Se tiver maiores dúvidas, sugiro postar uma nova pergunta, porque já estamos fugindo do escopo da original.

Comment: É isso mesmo que eu quero, salvar esse json. Eu já andei dando uma olhada sobre o node.js e gostei muito, quero mesmo testar com ele. Então agora devo criar uma nova pergunta sobre como salvar dados no json do servidor, certo?

Comment: Isso, @Pedro. Mas já adianto: seria legal você ter algum domínio de programação do lado do servidor antes de tentar isso.

Comment: Como eu não tenho esse conhecimento, você poderia me indicar algum link para que eu possa começar a estudar? @bfavaretto

Comment: @PedroGelli Agora você me pegou, não sei não...

Answer (score 6):

Um ótimo link para interpretação de sintaxe de JSON é este: http://json.parser.online.fr/ qualquer JSON, que este site interpretar OK sem erros, você poderá utilizar no seu código, porém sobre o seu JSON:

```
[
   { titulo: 'ET', ano: 1982 },
   { titulo: 'Indiana Jones', ano: 1981 }
]
```

Este JSON acima é incorreto, veja que se colocar ele no json parser online ele acusa erros.

```
{
    "Titulo": "Até que a sorte nos separe",
    "segundo": "segundo valor",
    "terceiro": "terceiro valor, o ultimo valor não precisa de virgula"
}
```

Este JSON acima, é correto, ele não acusará erros, porém não deves utiliza-lo porque você precisa denotar um objeto para acessar `objeto.propriedade` como eu estou fazendo no Array logo abaixo:

Aqui você tem um Array de Objetos "Filme" onde você pode usa-lo para iterar seus filmes.

```js
ObjetoJSON = {

    "filme":[
        {
            "titulo":"Titulo do seu filme",
            "segundo":"segundo valor",
            "terceiro":"terceiro valor, o ultimo valor não precisa de virgula"
        },
        {
            "titulo":"Titulo do seu filme 2",
            "segundo":"segundo valor 2",
            "terceiro":"terceiro valor, o ultimo valor não precisa de virgula 2"
        },
        {
            "titulo":"Titulo do seu filme 3",
            "segundo":"segundo valor 3",
            "terceiro":"terceiro valor, o ultimo valor não precisa de virgula 3"
        }
    ]

};
ObjetoJSON.filme[0] //seu objeto json do seu filme [0]
ObjetoJSON.filme[0].titulo //seu valor do titulo do filme [0]
ObjetoJSON.filme[0].segundo //o "segundo" valor do filme [0]
ObjetoJSON.filme[0].terceiro// o "terceiro" valor do filme [0]
```

EDIT:

Para utilizar o JSON dentro de um arquivo da extensão *.json resgatado de um AJAX Request você deve fazer o seguinte:

Utilize o seguinte código JSON (desta vez sem definição por variável) no seu arquivo *.json:

```js
{
  "filme":[
        {
            "titulo":"Titulo do seu filme",
            "segundo":"segundo valor",
            "terceiro":"terceiro valor, o ultimo valor não precisa de virgula"
        },
        {
            "titulo":"Titulo do seu filme 2",
            "segundo":"segundo valor 2",
            "terceiro":"terceiro valor, o ultimo valor não precisa de virgula 2"
        },
        {
            "titulo":"Titulo do seu filme 3",
            "segundo":"segundo valor 3",
            "terceiro":"terceiro valor, o ultimo valor não precisa de virgula 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

E use este código javascript para que você entenda o JSON, e depois adapte ele do seu jeito que você usa:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'js/vendor/testedb.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('Titulo: ' + data.filme[0].titulo + ' Segundo: ' + data.filme[0].segundo);
    },
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert("some problem");
        }
    },

});
```

Comment: Eu poderia criar mais de um objeto json no mesmo arquivo json? Um para cada filme?

Comment: Sim, vou adicionar um exemplo

Comment: @dcastro eu estava utilizando o exemplo que o OP citou, mas agora há um belo exemplo abaixo.

Comment: A definição do objeto "ObjetoJSON" fica dentro do arquivo JSON? E o "ObjetoJSON.filme[0]" eu coloquei em um console.log ao clicar mas diz indefinido. Eu coloquei no arquivo JSON toda a definição do "ObjetoJSON".

Comment: Porque você precisa de um "Arquivo JSON" ? Execute todo meu bloco de código no javascript, você verá que o javascript criará a variável "ObjetoJSON" e definirá ela como um JSON, você pode alterar este nome, é apenas uma variável, lembre-se.

Comment: Entendi o que você quer fazer, @PedroGelli. Mas você precisa resgatar este arquivo JSON mesmo do servidor ? ele será dinamico? se sim, me avise pois tenho que editar minha resposta. Se não, você pode apenas declarar o JSON no JavaScript e acessar exatamente como eu mostrei.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Eu sugeri usar um JSON no servidor pois o objetivo dele é aprender (veja [comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2958/como-inserir-dados-em-mysql-com-jquery-javascript-sem-usar-php#comment3452_2964) na outra pergunta), e com isso ele já aprenderia como o funciona acesso a dados a partir do cliente, na vida real.

Comment: @bfavaretto o que gerou uma grande confusão em minha mente com a pergunta dele, mas tudo bem, né. Pelo menos consegui entender e por ultimo edit postei o que ele queria.

Answer (score 3):

```
{
    "nome": "Kadu",
    "idade": "25"
}
```

Isto é um Objeto que armazena um nome e uma idade.

```
{
    "pessoas": [
        { "nome": "José", "idade": "80" },
        { "nome": "Maria", "idade": "60"}
    ]
}
```

Isto é um array de pessoas. Toda vez que você tiver uma coleção ou conjunto de dados, você pode armazená-los num array e conseguirá iterar por esse array usando uma estrutura de loop.

Comment: Obrigado, então a forma como a pessoa me respondeu antes desse tópico esta escrita errada né?

Comment: Só faltva o "{}"

Comment: Acredito que não era só isso @NovoK, pois em javascript o JSON citado por ele, no primeiro exemplo, jamais rodaria, pois o Javascript entenderia `titulo` e `ano` como uma variável não declarada: `undefined variable`.

Comment: Opa, isso mesmo!

Comment: De fato o json que eu tinha sugerido era inválido pela falta das aspas, mas o objeto por fora não é necessário. O json pode ser simplesmente um array.

Answer (score 3):

No seu primeiro exemplo, vc está criando um vetor com dois objetos.
A sintaxe correta seria a segunda, e para criar mais objetos vc tem que fazer da seguinte forma:

```
[
    {
        "Titulo": "Até que a sorte nos separe",
        "duração": "120 min"
    },
    {
        "Titulo": "Matrix",
        "duração": "140 min"
    }
]
```

Comment: A raiz de um documento json deve ser ou um objecto, ou um array. A raiz desse formato é inválida porque tem dois objectos

Comment: Está correto dcastro, eu resumi a resposta demais.

Comment: @dcastro Tem certeza? Na especificação do JSON não fala disso. O http://jsonlint.com diz que é válido. `JSON.parse` também aceita um array.

Comment: @bfavaretto, acho que ele estava me corrigindo do jeito que eu postei antes, no caso sem os colchetes [].
[]s

Comment: @GabrielRibeiro Ah, eu li errado, achei que ele estava dizendo que a raiz tinha de ser um objeto e não um array.

Answer (score 2):

Cara seria legal também você dar uma lida na documentação do JSON, segue os links:

MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JSON

JSON:
http://www.json.org/

Eu vejo muito as pessoas confundindo o formato JSON com Object Literal, veja um exemplo:

JSON:

```
{"nome":"Fabio", "sobrenome":"Silva", "idade":35}
```

Object Literal:

```
{nome:"Fabio", sobrenome:"Silva", idade:35}
```

Eu não posso colocar mais do que dois links ainda, mas tem bastante coisa na net que pode esclarecer mais sobre como você deve trabalhar com o JSON, e a diferença que existe do Object Literal.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Concordo, o javascript entende qualquer palavra que não for reservada como uma variável. Que na maioria dos casos será indefinida utilizando um JSON desta maneira.

Answer (score 1):

O primeiro exemplo trata-se de um array json com 2 objectos, cada objecto tem um título e um ano.

O segundo exemplo trata-se de um simples objecto json com 3 propriedades (3 pares key - value).

Eu recomendo um formato semelhante ao do primeiro exemplo (um array de objectos) para representar uma coleção de filmes.

```
["titulo 1", "titulo 2"]
```

Comment: Mas então porque ele não funciona no meu código? Eu coloquei ele no Json Parser Online e realmente da erro.

Comment: O parser falha porque as keys (titulo e ano) devem estar entre aspas "". Como estou no telemovel nao consigo ajudar mais, mas procura no google "javascript parse json array"

Answer (score 1):

Outro site que eu gosto de acessar para edição de JSON é este:

http://jsoneditoronline.org/

É bem simples de utilizar.