# Como Fazer isso em Javascript (Listando produtos por categoria,De acordo com o Banco de Dados)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

Eu estou fazendo um aplicativo pra fazer pedido é o meu TCC e estou com dificuldade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso o quê? No título você pede em JavaScript, no corpo da pergunta em PHP, mas em nenhum momento você fala o que quer fazer de fato. Por favor, leia o guia de [ask] e busque melhorar sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu estou querendo em Javascript

Comment: Essa imagem mostra a parte que você já fez? Em que parte está tendo dificuldades exatamente?

Comment: Então eu so fiz a parte do design e eu quero que os produtos sejam separados por categorias como na imagem acima.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você pode usar o reduce para criar um novo array agrupado pelas categorias.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
    var dados = [
      {
        nome: 'cerveja',
        categoria: 'bebida'
      },
      {
       nome: 'suco',
       categoria: 'bebida'
      },
      {
       nome: 'joelho',
       categoria: 'salgado'
      },
      {
       nome: 'pastel',
       categoria: 'salgado'
      }
    ]

    var novoArray = dados.reduce(function(prev,curr){
      prev[curr.categoria] = prev[curr.categoria] || [];
      prev[curr.categoria].push(curr);
      return prev;
    },{});

    console.log(novoArray)
```

Comment: Mas como fazer o banco interagir com o array?

Comment: Bom, acredito que você tenha que criar um "serviço" no back-end que faça essa ponte. 
Dá uma lida nesse tópico [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2958/como-inserir-dados-em-db-com-jquery-javascript-sem-usar-php), talvez ele te ajude.